# Rails nested routes for create method smart_listing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, routes

I have two models: apartment and room. Apartment has_many rooms, and rooms belongs_to apartment. I use smart_listing gem as ajax form. I show my table in edit_apartment_path

```
= render 'rooms/index' # index is partial
```

And I add this to my apartment_controller

```
def edit
    @rooms = smart_listing_create :rooms,
                                      Room.where(apartment_id: params[:apartment_id]),
                                      partial: "rooms/list"
end
```

Now I must set paths for my form

```
= simple_form_for object, url: object.new_record? ? apartment_rooms_path : apartment_room_path(id: object),
                   remote: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal"} do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.button :submit
```

I can edit my created room, but I can't create new room in apartment. My error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches {:action=>"edit", :apartment_id=>nil, :controller=>"rooms", :id=>#<Room id: 83, title: "dawawd">, created_at: "2016-02-11 10:36:30", updated_at: "2016-02-11 10:36:30", apartment_id: 4>} missing required keys: [:apartment_id]:
```

My routes

```
resources :apartments do
      resources :rooms
    end
```

Propably smart_listing not support nested routes. Anyone have idea? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's simple example of nested routes with smart_listing. I think that should cover the subject. 
I used `Rails 4.2`, `ruby 2.2.0`, `smart_listing 1.1.2`

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
  resources :bios
end
root 'users#index'
```

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :bio
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bio, allow_destroy: true
  scope :like, ->(args) { where("email like '%#{args}%' OR name like '%#{args}%' OR surname like '%#{args}%'")}
end
```

**models/bio.rb**

```
class Bio < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include SmartListing::Helper::ControllerExtensions
  helper  SmartListing::Helper
  before_action :set_user, only: [:update, :destroy]

  def index
    users_scope = User.all.includes(:bio)
    users_scope = users_scope.like(params[:filter]) if params[:filter]
    # @users = smart_listing_create :users, users_scope, partial: "users/list", page_sizes: [5, 7, 13, 26]
    @users = smart_listing_create(:users, users_scope, partial: 'users/list',
                               sort_attributes: [
                                [:name, 'name'],
                                [:surname, 'surname'],
                                [:email, 'email'],
                                [:city, 'bio.city'],
                                [:birthday, 'bio.birthday']
                               ],
                               default_sort: { start_at: 'desc' }
                               )
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_bio
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.save
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.includes(:bio).find(params[:id])
    @user.bio.build if @user.bio.nil?
  end

  def update
    @user.update(user_params)
  end

  def delete
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
  end

  private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :surname, :email, :bio_attributes => [:birthday, :city])
  end
end
```

**views/users/index.html.haml**

```
= smart_listing_controls_for(:users, {class: "form-inline text-right"}) do
  .form-group.filter.input-append
    = text_field_tag :filter, '', class: "search form-control", 
                          placeholder: "Search...", autocomplete: :off
= smart_listing_render :users
```

**views/users/_list.html.haml**

```
- unless smart_listing.empty?
  %table.table.table-striped
    %thead
      %th= smart_listing.sortable "Name", :name
      %th= smart_listing.sortable "Surname", :surname
      %th= smart_listing.sortable "Email", :email
      %th= smart_listing.sortable "City", :city
      %th= smart_listing.sortable "Birthday", :birthday
    %tbody
      - smart_listing.collection.each do |o|
        %tr.editable{data: {id: o.id}}
          = smart_listing.render object: o, partial: "users/user", locals: {object: o}
      = smart_listing.item_new colspan: 6, link: new_user_path
  = smart_listing.paginate
  = smart_listing.pagination_per_page_links
- else
  %p.warning No users
```

**views/users/_user.html.haml**

```
%td= object.name
%td= object.surname
%td= object.email
%td= object.bio.city
%td= object.bio.birthday
%td.actions= smart_listing_item_actions [ {name: :edit, url: edit_user_path(object)}, {name: :destroy, url: user_path(object), confirmation: "Are you sure you want to delete this?"}]
```

**views/users/_form.html.haml**

```
%td{colspan: 6}
  = form_for object, url: object.new_record? ? users_path : user_path(object), 
                 remote: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal"} do |f|
    %p
      Name: 
      = f.text_field :name
    %p
      Surname: 
      = f.text_field :surname
    %p
      Email: 
      = f.text_field :email

    = f.fields_for :bio do |ff|
      %p
        Birthday
        = ff.date_field :birthday
      %p
        City
        = ff.text_field :city

    = f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary"
    %button.btn.btn-link.cancel Cancel
```

**views/users/create.js.erb**

```
<%= smart_listing_item :users, :create, @user, @user.persisted? ? "users/user" : "users/form" %>
```

**views/users/edit.js.erb**

```
<%= smart_listing_item :users, :edit, @user, "users/form" %>
```

**views/users/destroy.js.erb**

```
<%= smart_listing_item :users, :destroy, @user %>
```

**views/users/index.js.erb**

```
<%= smart_listing_update(:users) %>
```

**views/users/new.js.erb**

```
<%= smart_listing_item :users, :new, @user, "users/form" %>
```

**views/users/update.js.erb**

```
<%= smart_listing_item :users, :update, @user, @user.valid? ? "users/user" : "users/form" %>
```

Comment: Beautiful example :) !!

Comment: Was this helpful? Did You get it to work in your app?

Answer (score 0):

you should receive to form `@apartment` also, and in this case if your `@room.persisted?` form recive request to edit, else to create:

```
= simple_form_for [@apartment, @room], remote: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal"} do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.button :submit
```

Comment: I tested form, and when I create new object, it create item in db successfully, but there's something wrong with routes from smart_listing gem. Why it create successfully item in my db and return some bad routes ?

Comment: take a look at console logs, what route do you have when you update object?

Comment: `ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches {:action=>"edit", :apartment_id=>nil, :controller=>"rooms", :id=>#<Room id: 83, title: "dawawd">, created_at: "2016-02-11 10:36:30", updated_at: "2016-02-11 10:36:30", apartment_id: 4>} missing required keys: [:apartment_id]:` The same, but item is successfully created in db. Maybe my create.js.erb file for smart_listing is wrong :/

Comment: But how send params in this code?
`<%= smart_listing_item :rooms, :create, @room,
                       @room.valid? ? "rooms/room" : "rooms/form" %>`
When I add params manually I have error: `undefined method 'persisted?'`